# Angular UI-Bootstrap 0.7.0 Collapse

Tags: angularjs, toggle, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the collapse feature of UI-Bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) but when I use the collapse/toggle it loses the data and just returns "true".

Here is a Plunker to show my issue, http://plnkr.co/edit/e689Wureay8AMZQ9IIno?p=preview

A snippet from the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names | filter:radioModel:true">
 <span ng-model="namesList" ng-click="name = !name">Toggle collapse {{name.firstName}}</span>
 <hr>
 <div ng-show="name">
 <div class="well well-large">{{name}} -</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting `name` in the `ng-click` here: `ng-click="name = !name"`. That will make `name` `true` or `false`, depending on how many times `ng-click` was invoked.

What you want is to toggle a property on the model to `collapse/uncollapse` the following detail:

```html
    <div ng-repeat="name in names | filter:radioModel:true" >
      <!-- change the property name.collapsed -->
      <span ng-model="namesList" ng-click="name.collapsed = !name.collapsed">Toggle collapse {{name.firstName}}</span>
      <hr>

      <!-- use ng-hide to "collapse" -->
      <div ng-hide="!!name.collapsed">
        <div class="well well-large">{{name}} -</div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/at7ceCYDXwWWlqUlKnkQ?p=preview

Comment: OMG!.. how could I not see that haha!... Thanks!

Comment: @Mackelito Happens with everyone. :)